# MongoDB error to push data in mongoose schema from self define methods like generateAuthToken

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, restful-authentication

I'm facing a problem to push data on collection in mongodb

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
const _=require('lodash');
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise=global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydata');

var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var UserSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    tokens:[{
        access:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        token:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
    }]
});

UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken=function(){
    var user=this;
    var access='auth';
    var token=jwt.sign({_id:user._id.toHexString(),access},'123abc').toString();

    user.tokens.push({access,token});
    return user.save().then((token)=>{
        return token;
    });
};

var User=mongoose.model('users',UserSchema);

app.post('/testapp',(req,res)=>{
    var body=_.pick(req.body,['email']);
    var user=new User(body);

    user.save().then(()=>{
        return user.generateAuthToken();
    }).then((token)=>{
        res.send(user);
    }).catch((e)=>{
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log(`server is 

    //----------

    port:${3000}`);
});
```

In result email is saved but it can't push data in token and display
this type of error in postman.

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "Unknown modifier: $pushAll",
    "driver": true,
    "index": 0,
    "code": 9,
    "errmsg": "Unknown modifier: $pushAll"
}
```